# Connect 4 troubles with placing the tiles

Tags: java, arrays

In my Connect 4 code it doesn't the tiles on the board at all. 
The checkOccupied method is the malfunctioning method in this case. This is a 6 by 7 board.

```
public static void checkOccupied(int slot){
  for(int i = 6; i < 0; i++){
       if(board[i][slot-1] != "X" || board[i][slot-1] != "O"){
           if(turns % 2 == 0){
               board[i][slot-1] = playerOne;
               break;
           }
           else{
               board[i][slot-1] = playerTwo;
               break;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

The printed board does not change (it does update).

Comment: Your logic is wrong. Look carefully at your for loop - does `int i = 6; i  < 0; i++)` really look right to you? If it does, use a pencil and paper and write down a few passes through that loop. If it still makes sense to you, ask your instructor to go over basic arithmetic with you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't notice your comment. Remove it.

Comment: @ManhLe: Thank you. :-)